# How to install and use the Jquery DataTable in angular2+?

Tags: angular, datatables

I am learning the angular4. I want to use the [Jquery DataTable Plugin](https://datatables.net/) in the angular application. But i have no idea about how to install and use this plugin in angular application. Can any one guide me?

Comment: Are you using webpack or angular cli?
First of all you need to inlude jquery plugin, then you can use it as usual jquery lib.

Comment: I am using angular cli

Comment: For example: https://medium.com/@NetanelBasal/typescript-integrate-jquery-plugin-in-your-project-e28c6887d8dc

Comment: You can show how to run that from here : https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-datatable

Comment: I want to use https://datatables.net/ plugin. @FerasAlSous

Comment: Then how to install the Datatable plugin @AntonLee

Comment: `npm install datatables.net  datatables.net-dt`